# How to know the location of the library that I load in Python?

Tags: python, path

import ABC loads ABC from somewhere. How can I know the 'somewhere'?

I may be able to check the paths in `sys.path` one by one, but I wonder if I can find it in Python.

### More Questions

1. When I load library with 'from ABC import *', how can I know where ABC is located?
2. Can 'class xyz' know where it is located when it is called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> import abc
>>> abc.__file__
'C:\\Program Files\\Python31\\lib\\abc.py'
```

See [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#index-855).

for more thorough inspection you could use [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> from abc import *
>>> inspect.getfile(ABCMeta)
'C:\\Program Files\\Python31\\lib\\abc.py'
```